# Need ActionScript 3 coding for input boxes that will determine amount of color fill in a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, input, adobe

If I put a numerical value in an input textbox1 and another value in input textbox2, then the percentage of both these input boxes will determine how much boxA will fill. For example, I put the value 10000 in textbox1 and 5000 in textbox2, then boxA will fill 50%.

Help in coding. I am a graphic designer and new to AS3 coding.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As much as any of us sympathize with the fact you are new and learning, **StackOverflow** is not a free code delivery service. You are supposed to provide your efforts in form of code that misbehaves or results in error, then we help you understand why it misbehaves and where are the said error comes from. Feel free to consult this nice asking guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @Organis suggested you should try to attempt to solve the problem yourself and show the code used in your efforts so that we may assist you.

I will provide some code to get you started but you should try to understand this code and expand upon it yourself to make it your own.

```
// Create 2 text boxes.
var input1:TextField = new TextField();
var input2:TextField = new TextField();

// Set the type, background and position of both text boxes.
input1.type = input2.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
input1.background = input2.background = true;
input2.y = input1.height + 10;

// Only allow characters 0 through 9 to be entered into the text boxes.
input1.restrict = input2.restrict = "0-9";

// Add text boxes to the stage.
addChild(input1);
addChild(input2);

// Add event listeners so that each time the contents of either text boxes
// gets changed, the handleChange function will be called.
input1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, handleChange);
input2.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, handleChange);

function handleChange(e:Event):void {
    // Convert the text content of the text boxes to numbers.
    const value1:Number = Number(input1.text);
    const value2:Number = Number(input2.text);
    // Ratio between the numbers as a fraction - e.g. 1000, 500 -> 0.5
    const fraction:Number = value2 / value1;
    // Ratio between the numbers as a percentage - e.g. 1000, 500 -> 50
    const percentage:Number = fraction * 100;
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you want when you say this should determine the how much boxA will fill.

If boxA is a MovieClip you could control its opacity:

```
boxA.alpha = fraction;
```

Or could control its height etc.

```
boxA.scaleY = fraction;
```

I'm sure you can experiment with this yourself.